# Cannot specify input dataset in shiny dashboard

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shinyapps, shiny-reactivity

I am trying to make a shiny dashboard. I have two datasets, and based upon the selection of the datasets figures will be generate in the tab panels. However, by default only the last dataset that has been loaded/read is selected and I cannot select the first dataset. Even though I have made it default selection.

Below is my code.

```
library(shinydashboard)
library(uwot)
library(DESeq2)
library(gridExtra)
library(tidyverse)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(DESeq2)
library(pheatmap)
library(DEGreport)
library(vsn)
library(RColorBrewer)
library("genefilter")
library(org.Hs.eg.db)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)
library(fgsea)
library(clusterProfiler)
library(ggplot2)


set_1<-load("C:/Users/abn/Documents/Shiny/DashBoardTutorial/TeData2.RData")
set_2<-load("C:/Users/abn/Documents/Shiny/DashBoardTutorial/TeData1.RData")
data_list = list(set_1=set_1,set_2=set_2)

ui <- dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(title = "Data Visualizer", titleWidth = 300),
    dashboardSidebar(
        width = 300,
        sidebarMenu(

            menuItem("Datasets",  icon = icon("cog"),
                     selectInput("Datasets", "Datasets:", choices = list("sample1" = "set_1", "sample2" = "set_2"),
                                 selected = "set_1")),
            menuItem("Quality Control", tabName = "widgets", icon = icon("th")),
            menuItem("Differential Genes", tabName = "widgets2", icon = icon("th")),
            menuItem("Downstream", tabName = "widgets3", icon = icon("th"))
            
         )
    ),
    ## Body content
    dashboardBody(
        tabItems(
            # First tab content
            # Second tab content
            tabItem(tabName="widgets",
                   h2("widgets"),
                   plotOutput("widgets"),
                    
            ),
            tabItem(tabName = "widgets2",
                    h2("Widgets2 tab content"),
                    
            ),
            tabItem(tabName = "widgets3",
                    h2("Widgets3 tab content"),
                    plotOutput("widgets3"),
                    
            )

        )
    )
)


server <- function(input, output) {

    
    datasetInput <- reactive({
        df <- data_list[[input$Datasets]]
        })
    
        output$widgets <- renderPlot({
            datasetInput()
            par(mfrow=c(1,2))
            
            boxplot(counts(dds, normalized=F), outline=F, col=dds$condition, medcol = "white", cex.axis=0.6, main="Without Normalization")
            boxplot(counts(dds, normalized=T), outline=F, col=dds$condition, medcol = "white", cex.axis=0.6, main="Normalized")
            
            })
        
        }

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I am sure that I am missing a small trick, could anyone of you shiny masters help me out.

Or may be there is a better way to do the above procedure.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Perhaps you should use `multiple=TRUE` option in your `selectInput` to pick both datasets.  At the moment, it is only picking one dataset.

Comment: What is `dds` ? Can you share the data that you are using?

Comment: @RonakShah This is the data that one gets after running RNA seq pipeline using DESeq2. I am trying to upload it in shiny. The function dds comes from the same. Could you please try to use mt cars and iris datasets to get a reproducible example.

Comment: @YBS still doesn't work :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have access to both datasets, you plot them both and display the selection.  Try this

```
data_list = list(set_1=mtcars,set_2=iris)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Data Visualizer", titleWidth = 300),
  dashboardSidebar(
    width = 300,
    sidebarMenu(
      
      menuItem("Datasets",  icon = icon("cog"),
               selectInput("Datasets", "Datasets:", choices = list("sample1" = "set_1", "sample2" = "set_2"),
                           selected = "set_1")),
      menuItem("Quality Control", tabName = "widgets", icon = icon("th")),
      menuItem("Differential Genes", tabName = "widgets2", icon = icon("th")),
      menuItem("Downstream", tabName = "widgets3", icon = icon("th"))
      
    )
  ),
  ## Body content
  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      # First tab content
      # Second tab content
      tabItem(tabName="widgets",
              h2("widgets"),
              #plotOutput("widgets"),
              uiOutput("widgets")
      ),
      tabItem(tabName = "widgets2",
              h2("Widgets2 tab content"),
              
      ),
      tabItem(tabName = "widgets3",
              h2("Widgets3 tab content"),
              plotOutput("widgets3"),
              
      )
    )
  )
)


server <- function(input, output) {
  
  # datasetInput <- reactive({
  #   df <- data_list[[input$Datasets]]
  # })
  # 
  # output$widgets <- renderPlot({
  #   datasetInput()
  #   par(mfrow=c(1,2))
  #   
  #   boxplot(counts(dds, normalized=F), outline=F, col=dds$condition, medcol = "white", cex.axis=0.6, main="Without Normalization")
  #   boxplot(counts(dds, normalized=T), outline=F, col=dds$condition, medcol = "white", cex.axis=0.6, main="Normalized")
  #   
  # })
  
  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    boxplot(mpg ~ cyl , data=mtcars)
  })
  output$plot2 <- renderPlot({
    boxplot(Sepal.Length ~ Species , data=iris)
  })
  
  output$widgets <- renderUI({
    if (input$Datasets=="set_1") { plotOutput("plot1")
    }else plotOutput("plot2")
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image: output]